# Angular Routing from CanActivate Guard when URL is manually entered not possible due to Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular, angular5

Trying to stop access to a few routes if the user directly accesses them using a bookmark, or by manually entering the URL.  The routes are a set of chained routes in a specific order.  For example, like a wizard.

In the past I didn't have any issues using `canActivate` and using a service, which if it didn't have the proper data indicating the previous route states were accessed (ie. page 1 before page 2 etc) it would route the user to the initial route (page 1), but after using `enableTracing` and testing this on a couple quickly generated components it seems that as the application is loading and accesses a `CanActivate` guard that prevents access to the route, that invoking `this.router.navigate(['/example/route/path']);` doesn't seem to make it to its destination (page 1) if page 2 or more is accessed directly.

Putting a `TestComponent` that isn't lazy loaded in the `AppRoutingModule` or using the top-level `not-found` route works, but absolutely nothing in the `MainModule` is routeable.  So it seems to be potentially related to lazy loaded modules that contain lazy loaded modules.

Anyone found a way around this?  Or is this just another issue related to lazy loading in Angular like `entryComponents` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689994/1148107.

I'm not sure why the application was set up this way so worst case I'll try and push for a quick refactor and flatten the lazy loading of feature modules.

**CanActivate**

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  if (this.storeService.hasAccess) {
    return true;
  }

  this.router.navigate(['/store/page/1']); // Doesn't route to page 1
  return false;
}
```

**AppRoutingModule Routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  // ...
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }
];
```

**MainRoutingModule Routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'store',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'store',
        loadChildren: './store/store.module#StoreModule'
      },
      // ...
    ]
  }
];
```

**StoreRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page/1',
        component: Page1Component,
        data: {
          title: 'Store'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'page/2',
        component: Page2Component,
        // Redirects to a blank page instead of page 1 when directly 
        // accessed by a browser bookmark
        canActivate: [CanActivateStoreGuard], 
        data: {
          title: 'Store'
        }
      },
      // ...
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Can you add the route configuration and how you're using `canActivate`.

Comment: isn't this the use case for canLoad? https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules

Comment: Hi @cgTag I've added a code example

Comment: Hi @bryan60, they should be able to access the module, but not the page 2 route component if the service indicates they haven't visited page 1.  Which works if you try and route directly to page 2, but fails if they manually enter the URL to access page 2.

Comment: You could subscribe to params/queryParams in the component. Keep a reference to the page number in a service, and check the service for page number in canActivate.

Comment: Hi @alphapilgrim that's actually what `hasAccess` in my service is technically doing, but if it fails `this.router.navigate(['/store/page/1'])` doesn't go to the page 1 route when that module is lazy loaded.

Comment: Can you try using `return true` in the `CanActivateStoreGuard` and see if this fixes the route navigate.

Comment: @cgTag appears to do the same thing where it seems to be trying to route, and the URL changes from `localhost:4300/store/page/2`, but instead of going to `localhost:4300/store/page/1` it goes to `localhost:4300` and doesn't load any route unless I stick a component that isn't lazy loaded into the `AppRoutingModule` and change where page 2 routes.

Comment: I'm going to try to post an answer, but I am not sure it will work for you but it is what I do and mine works.

Comment: OK I get it now, your problem is that you have different copies of the service due to a module being lazy loaded.  You need to create a core module and provide your service there to ensure it is a singleton.  https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#prevent-reimport-of-the-coremodule

Comment: @bryan60 that wouldn't explain why it wouldn't change routes to page 1, but it is a good thing to double check.

Comment: it would explain it if the storeService is duplicated and the duplicate copy believes the user has acces, ie if the default is just "true" and needs to be explicitly flipped to false.

Comment: @bryan60 the `StoreService` is in the `CoreModule` so there wouldn't be a duplicate copy

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the route change inside the observable that is subscribed to by the Angular router.

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
   return new Observable((subscriber) => {
       if (this.storeService.hasAccess) {
          subscriber.next(true);
       } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/store/page/1']);
          subscriber.next(false);
       }
       subscriber.complete();
   });
}
```

I can not verify if this will resolve your issue, but I remember running into this issue. When I look at my guards this is what I do.

**Updated:**

If the above doesn't work (I have my doubts), then you could try wrapping the route change in a `setTimeout`.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
 if (this.storeService.hasAccess) {
    return true;
 }

 window.setTimeout(()=> this.router.navigate(['/store/page/1']));

 return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cgTag for the help.  These don't work either, but since it only affects users that try to manually load the URL (or use a bookmark) and not normal application routing I guess I'll comment this as a bit of a UX issue and circle round to resolve it later.  I'll post anything I find.